# iTunes Store operation failed

Tags: ios, xcode, alamofire, bundle-identifier

I have a problem with one of my iOS application.
I try to validate archive in Organizer but i have this message :

> Archive validation failed with errors : Archive validation failed due
>   to the issues listed below. iTunes Store operation failed. No suitable
>   application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier
>   'org.alamofire.Alamofire' is correct.

i use Alamofire in this application and the bundle identifier is not recognized, it is the first time i have this problem, in the previous version uploaded no problem with alamofire !

EDIT : of course bundle identifier of my app is like 'com.organization.myApp' and is created on developer center, i already uploaded archive on iTunes connect with alamofire and no problem. But Alamofire has also a bundle identifier (com.alamofire.Alamofire) and this time it implies this issue.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I doubt that your bundle Id should be Alamofire. You need to set up a Bundle Identifier within your iTunes Developer account and use that

Comment: Thanks Flexicoder, but if i use the bundle identifier of alamofire, there is an another error that tell : Archive validation failed with errors : Archive validation failed due to the issues listed below. iTunes Store operation failed. No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier ''com.organization.myApp" is correct. !

Comment: You need to read the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

Answer (score 1):

It clearly mentions that the bundle identifier of your app is not matching with the bundle identifier on iTunes record for your app. Are you sure you are archiving the correct Target from your workspace?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. The **wondering part is that bundle id (`com.xyzcompany.abcappname`) exists in Bundle Id section of my apple developer account.**

The solution was to **clean Xcode, delete the derived data content and then start Archive.**

In your case the **bundle id seems to be reserved type (use of `alamofire`)**. Try changing your Bundle Id. For eg. `com.YourCompanyName.AppName`